# Deploy a Django Site with another folder for static files

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

My enviroment is with Django 1.10.7, PostgreSQL 9.4 and Nginx 1.6 with Gunicorn

I have a global folder called static for common static files to use in sub apps, then i set another folder for production mode with the name 'static_root':

in my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

in my urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += (static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    urlpatterns += (static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT))
```

when debug is true all work perfect, but in production mode the site not see the static files

i set the location in nginx configuration too

thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer to my question,

the problem was that i set in the nginx configuration: root

```
location /static {
    root /var/projects/project/static_root;
}
```

the correct way is: alias

```
location /static {
    alias /var/projects/project/static_root;
}
```